# Cant Find GridView in WPF

Tags: wpf, gridview

As my question suggests I am unable to find GridView in WPF toolbox.

I have tried to Add it from WPF Components. But there also I did not find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control name is DataGrid. I think you are looking for this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx

Here is the usage

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProject}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single">
```

Comment: yes, exactly I am looking for this kind of control. In DataGrid I cant find the property DataGrid.DataSource

Comment: @Vishal I have updated the answer. You can see who to set source of it.

Comment: Just google it you will find it. Or simply what you can do is that add <DataGrid Width=100 Height 100/> in your XAML. It will show DataGrid in your view. And then you can set properties and events using properties window,